# Is it possible to use i18n localization for redux Actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I was trying to implement i18n localization for Redux Action functions, but i constantly recieve different hook errors. When i implemented i18n this way i recieve error.

*Line 428:17:  React Hook "useTranslation" is called in function "sendDataRequest" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.*

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const sendDataRequest = (requestId) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(sendDataRequest());
      await dataAPI.sendDataRequest({ requestId });
      notification.success({
        message: t('infoPage.requestSentSuccessfully'),      
     });
      dispatch(sendDataSuccess());
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(sendDataFailure());
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Then i moved **const { t } = useTranslation();** inside of return statement.
But then i recieved another error [image]
It looks like I obviously using it wrong here.
But i cannot find any examples on i18n being used in Actions.
Does anyone knows is it even possible to use i18b in Actions?

Comment: You must use react hooks inside react function component. This is the rule. You need to refactor your code. Why not create a custom hook which uses `useTranslation` hook internally and calls the `notification.success()` method after the data request finished?

Answer (score 5):

Check out https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/909

You need to gain access to your `i18next` instance. The one you create somewhere in your codebase. With this instance you can simply call `i18n.t("my.translation.key")` to translate. This is completely independent from react.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

1. You need to import your i18n instance in your actions/reducer:

   import i18n from '../i18n_init_file';
2. After that you could use the instance inside your actions like that:

   i18n.t('STRING_TO_TRANSLATE');

   or

   i18n.changeLanguage('NEW_LOCALE').then();